# Отображение '\t' в консоли на Си

Tags: c

изучаю книгу "Язык программирования С" Кернигана и Ритчи.

Дошел до упражнения 1.21. Напишите программу entab, которая бы заменяла пустые строки,состоящие из одних пробелов, строками, содержащими минимальное количество
табуляций и дополнительных пробелов, — так, чтобы заполнять то же пространство. Используйте те же параметры табуляции, что и в программе detab. Если для заполнения места
до следующей границы табуляции требуется один пробел или один символ табуляции, то
что следует предпочесть?

Мой код:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int c, probel = 0;

int main()
{
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if(c != '_')
        {
            if(probel>0)
            {
                for(;probel>0;probel--)
                {
                putchar('_');
                }
            }
            putchar(c);
        }
        else
        {
            probel++;
            if(probel > 3)
            {
                putchar('\t');
                probel = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Это тестовая версия. Для наглядности я заменил символ пробела символом нижнего подчеркивания.

При вводе в консоль данной строки:

```
9___9____9_____9___9
```

На выходе Я получаю следующее:

```
9___9   9   _9___9
```

Т.е. таб заменяет 3 символа подчеркивания. Но если ввести так

```
____9
```

Выход:

```
    9
```

Т.е. таб заменяет уже 4 символа.

Вопрос: Почему так? И в чем моя ошибка?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел ещё одну закономерность. Если перед подчеркивание есть 1 символ, то таб будет на 1 позицию меньше, если 2 символа, то таб на 2 позиции меньше, если 4 символа, то таб отображается нормально. Если 5 символов перед подчеркивание, то таб опять на 1 позицию меньше и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: консоль выравнивает `\t` до ровного столбика, номер которого нацело делится на 4 или 8, смотря какие настройки у консоли. Какая у вас задача у вас такое и решение.

Comment: """бы заменяла **пустые строки**,состоящие из одних пробелов""".

Comment: Stanislav Volodarskiy да, я согласен что мое решение зашло за грани задачи, сейчас я это понял. Но главный вопрос у меня возник ниже. Его я и пытался понять. Спасибо AlexGlebe что показал мне на мою ошибку. Наверное я все таки не очень внимательно читаю так как где то упустил то, что консоль выравнивает табы по столбикам.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем кто ответил, особенно AlexGlebe. Переписал код и все заработало как надо.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int posiciya = 0;
int probel = 0;
int c;

int main()
{
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        posiciya++;
        if(posiciya > 4) posiciya = 1;
        
        if(c == '_' && posiciya == (probel + 1))
        {
            probel++;
            if(probel > 3)
            {
                putchar('\t');
                probel = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(;probel>0;probel--)
            {
                putchar('_');
            }
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```